# Serious issues with Proguard - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, proguard, noclassdeffounderror

### Background

Recently I've updated [**my app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager), and for some reason Proguard seem to ruin the code I've made, causing crashes on a very specific case, even though I didn't add any additional libraries.

The reason I'm so sure it's Proguard's fault is that when I tested it without exporting it, it ran fine.

### The problem

After seeing the crash reports' stack traces (and seeing that it does occur, by myself), I've ran the "proguardgui" tool and chose to retrace using the mapping file.

Sadly, instead of showing the real places that the code failed, it showed the exact same stack. I've tried to export the project again and use a new mapping file that was created by it, but I still get the same obfuscated stack trace.

Not only that, but the exception itself is very problematic: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError .

Here's the stack trace, though I don't think it's readable:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lb.app_manager.utils.r
at com.lb.app_manager.utils.e.c(Unknown Source)
at com.lb.app_manager.activities.app_list_activity.AppListActivity.onContextItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2620)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3864)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:133)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This occurs when I choose to share an app, which, for a very short time should show a progress dialog while running an AsyncTask, and then show a dialog of how you wish to share (just like on the screenshot of the play store link, available [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2700236) in case you can't see it ).

### What I've tried

I've tried to add logs in multiple places, and found out that the AsyncTask runs fine, but it doesn't reach "onPostExecute". I know this since I've put log at the end of "doInBackground" and at the beginning of "onPostExecute" .

This got even weirder, when I removed most of the code of "onPostExecute" and now I have only this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(final Void result)
  {
  Log.d("Applog","onPostExecute 0");
  super.onPostExecute(result);
  Log.d("Applog","onPostExecute 1");
  progressDialog.dismiss();
  }
```

It doesn't even reach the first line this way.

In the end, I've decided to merge 2 projects (that I made several versions ago), so that there won't be any Android library project that I made. Only a single one.

I've also removed a library that appears not being used (of Apache commons), but I can't believe this is the cause to the problem (because I didn't use it).

### The question

Why do such problems occur?

How can I avoid such a problem in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NoClassDefFoundError generally points to a problem in the build process: some class that is required doesn't end up in your application.

ProGuard prints out information in the build log about the input jars that it reads and the output jars that it writes. You can also specify

```
-printconfiguration configuration.txt
```

to get the complete configuration that ProGuard uses, including input and output. This should help you to find out if all expected input jars are present.

If you are using Eclipse to build your application, you may have run into a synchronization problem that seems to run ProGuard when not all compiled files have been written to disk yet. This mysterious problem has been reported a few times, but it is still unsolved. You should then try Ant or Gradle instead.

Comment: I see. It's weird though that what I did somehow solved it (merging the library project with the main project). does using the code you've written work even when using Eclipse?

Comment: For most developers, ProGuard seems to work fine in the Android plugin in Eclipse. A few developers report spurious problems that appear and disappear after seemingly unrelated changes in their projects. This suggests synchronization problems to me, but I've never been able to reproduce such problems myself.

Comment: I see. Thank you . I hope I won't see those issues again. I spent hours trying to understand why it occurs (and still I don't know), and finding a way to solve it (and I still don't know what should be done next time I see it).